# Redux error when trying to retrieve data from slice: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a simple todo app with ReactJS and Redux but i get an error when i try to retrieve the todos that i added to a list that is in the initial state. The error is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'list')

the error comes from this line:

```
export const selectTodos = (state) => state.todos.list;
```

**SLICE CODE:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  list: [],
};

export const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState,

  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.list = [...state.list, action.payload];
    },
  },
});

export const { addTodo } = todosSlice.actions;
export const selectTodos = (state) => state.todos.list;

export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

**APP.JSX:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo, selectTodos } from "./features/todos/todosSlice";

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const todos = useSelector(selectTodos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const createTodo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTodo = inputRef.current.value;
    dispatch(addTodo(newTodo));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="task..." ref={inputRef} />
        <button onClick={createTodo}>Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      <h2>Your Todos:</h2>
      {todos}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**INDEX.JSX:**

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./app/store";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**STORE.JS:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import todosReducer from "../features/todos/todosSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todo: todosReducer,
  },
});
```

If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Can you share index.js? And the code which includes react store?

Comment: i added them to the question

Comment: It appears you've a typo when creating the store, `todo: todosReducer` should be `todos: todosReducer` to match the selector function. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i used the wrong name to access the list. I used "todos" instead of "todo"